# Electron NPM install-app-deps electron-gyp (boilerplate hell)

Tags: npm, electron, electron-builder

As there are so many layers involved, I'm a bit lost in how to resolve the following (on linux) ...

Today I started to encounter failures with `npm i` involving electron apps. The initial error was to the tune of

```
"EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read" on `~./electron-gyp`.
```

Researching this indicates this is an attempt to read a directory (which it is) as a file. I thought it might be an `npm` issue as I upgraded it recently and so I reinstalled `node/npm` and removed all remnants including all electron folders, `npm` & `nodejs`. I thought a clean reinstall might be the best approach . . .

Reinstalled and configured all those, including moving global `npm` `node_modules` under the user account to remove any permission issues.

So far so good, however, the previous error now changes to

```
"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/joe/.electron-gyp'"
```

which is understandable as I removed this folder. I am unsure as to what electron or `npm` module should create and populate this folder.

Continued searching seems to be that the issue is associated in some manner with a call to `install-app-deps` from [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) but I can't seem to get that to work. I thought I'd ask for a little guidance here before I start to ask in that repo for assistance as I'm not positive the cause is there.

Creating the directory in advance to see the outcome results in:

```
[3] Error: /usr/bin/node exited with code 235
[3] Error output:
[3] npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/joe/.electron-gyp
[3] npm ERR! code EISDIR
[3] npm ERR! errno -21
[3] npm ERR! syscall read
[3] npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
[3] npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
[3] npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
[3] npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.
```

... which is sort of back to the start

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE1: Problem seems to be confirmed as stemming from `npm` and involving `electron-builder`. Issue ticket filed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug and resolved at source.